# Firebase:OrderbyChild on reference node, return NULL snapshot in onDataChange

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to invoke `oderByChild` on ref node, with date as nested item. It says:

> paymentIDs->userIDXX1->orderID->date:"1254785xxxx" return NULL in
>   `onDatechange()` .indexOn:date is also provided on node `paymentIDs`

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

Query listpayment = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("paymentIDs").orderByChild("date").startAt(fromdateinLong).endAt(todateinLong);

listpayment.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Log.e(TAG,"valueEventListener: OnDatachanged" );
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
//if not null, do something.
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG,"valueEventListener: OnCancelled" );
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @Alex Mamo. there's no crash. but datasnapshot is null.

Comment: In this case, please add more code and indicate where you get null.

Comment: @AlexMamo coded Added.

Comment: I see now. In this case please also add your database structure at least as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo, updated db info as PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `null` because you are missing a child, which is the id of the user. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query listpayment = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("paymentIDs").orderByChild("date").startAt(fromdateinLong).endAt(todateinLong);
```

to

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query listpayment = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
    .child("paymentIDs")
    .child(uid)
    .orderByChild("date")
    .startAt(fromdateinLong).endAt(todateinLong);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = ds.child("userId").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, userId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
listpayment.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

**Edit:**

According to your comments, you should know that using this database schema you **cannot** get all payments under all users. In Firebase there is no way to use wildcards. So a query like this:

```
Query listpayment = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
.child("paymentIDs")
.child(?)
.orderByChild("date")
.startAt(fromdateinLong).endAt(todateinLong);
```

Is not allowed. To solve this, there is an workaround, which implies you to duplicate data. So you should create another node in which you should add all the payments of all users. This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

So unfortunately, using the actual database structure you cannot achieve what you want.

Comment: but this will increase the efforts in reading the date per userID, what is the meaning of nested then?

Comment: Why are you saying that? Adding one more child it just points to the right node in the tree, right?

Comment: If there are 100+ users, then query has to be run 100+ times to get skim through the date. I want to query date across all the users at once.

Comment: My question is still same, orderbychild with nested item. I provided all the required info. but the answer is not what the question seeks.

Comment: Under a user object you can have multuple objects? In your screen I see only one.

Comment: under paymentIds, we have users, and each user will have as many as orders. -paymendIDs->UserId->OrderId(S)->{date:'xxxxx'}

Comment: So it can have more than one, right? So you want to get all payments under of all users, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185834/discussion-between-user755-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, if at all database structure needs a change, where/how it should look like?

Comment: As I already told you. Create a new node, add all payments there and use the following query: `Query listpayment = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("allPayments").orderByChild("date")
.startAt(fromdateinLong).endAt(todateinLong);` in which `allPayments` is the new node that I was talking about. It is clear now?

Comment: in that case,  another service listening on the paymentId node, and adding newly added orderid to the new node. this sounds kind of a task on server side rather on mobile app. Is there any feasibility to perfrom such kindof task on server?any pointers on how to achive this?

Comment: Yes, you should add another listener on that node, that's correct. According to your case, you can add on the server or on the client. But this is the only way you can solve this using your actual schema.

Comment: may I know how to add this on server ?

Comment: This is a quite different question. Unfortunately is not related with the first question at all. To know the answer for this new question, please post a new question so developers that know "server side functions" can help you.

Comment: If you think that my answer/comments for the initial question helped you, please consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!